# Find the ratio of A's chance of success to that of B given the following conditions?

Tags: probability

> A cube has four of its faces blank,one face is marked 5 and one face is marked 6.
>
> In a game involving throwing his cube,a person is said to have success,if he throws a numbered face.Two persons A and B participate in the game.A throws the cube thrice while B throws it once.Find the ratio of A's chance of success to that of B?

options:
a) $1/9$ b)$2/9$ c)$19/9$ d)$4/9$

My approach

Total possible outcomes A success is $6^3$

Total possible outcomes B success is $6$

Favourable outcomes  for A:$(2/6)^3$

Favourable outcomes  for B:(2/6)

P(A):P(B)=$1$/$9$

> I am not getting correct.Can anyone give me the hint:Why?

Comment: I guess, though it is not perfectly clear from the question, that a success for $A$ is defined as getting a number in at least one of the throws and not in all of them which is what you calculated.

Comment: Calculate the probability that $A$ does *not* have three failures.

Comment: @ShaharEven-DarMandel  Yes it is not given clearly.Why they have taken complementary part to match the Ans?

Answer (score 1):

Success over three throws is determined by success in *any* of these throws, not *each* of them.

Easiest way for $A$ is to consider the complementary probability: the probability of three failures in a row, which is ${(\frac 46)}^3 = {(\frac 23)}^3 = \frac{8}{27}$

Hence $A$'s chance of success = $1 - \frac{8}{27} = \frac{19}{27}$

B's chance of success is simply $\frac 26 = \frac 13$

The ratio is therefore $\frac{19}{9}$

Comment: It is not given clearly in the question.Why you have taken complementary part.Is it to match the Ans?

Comment: @Jack You need to find the chance of success for $A$. Success is determined by throwing *a* (meaning one) numbered face according to the question. I agree this question is fairly vague. But the most "reasonable" interpretation is that $A$ has three "tries". If he gets a numbered face on any try, he's succeeded. He only fails if he gets three blank faces in a row. That's why I found the complementary probability to begin with. It's just easier this way. By the way, I didn't try to match the answer, just worked it out without considering the options.

Comment: @Jack Since your problem is one of interpretation, then let's consider other "alternative" interpretations of the question. One possibility is to insist strictly on the singular "a" in the question. Meaning $A$ has to get *exactly* one numbered face in his three throws - one number, two blanks, in any order. But if they intended this, they should have emphasised *exactly* or *only* one number. Another possibility is saying he needs to get a number on *each* of the three throws. Again, if they'd intended this, they should've emphasised the *each*. Hence these two possibilities are less likely.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that A throws a numbered face at least once is $1-\left(\frac46\right)^{\color\red3}=\frac{19}{27}$.

The probability that B throws a numbered face at least once is $1-\left(\frac46\right)^{\color\red1}=\frac{9}{27}$.

So the ratio between A's chances of success and B's chances of success is $\dfrac{\frac{19}{27}}{\frac{9}{27}}=\dfrac{19}{9}$.